# Camunda: Use in an external Groovy script a provided Class

Tags: groovy, camunda

I want to use for scripting external Groovy Scripts.

To not copy a lot of code, I want to share classes.

I have:

```
- external_test.groovy
- Input.groovy
```

Running the `external_test.groovy` in Intellij works.

Input is a simple class:

```
package helpers

class Input {
    String serviceConfig
    String httpMethod
    String path
    LinkedHashMap headers = [:]
    String payload
    Boolean hasResponseJson
}
```

When the script is executed by Camunda, it cannot find the class:

```
import helpers.Input
...
```

And throws an Exception:

```
unable to resolve class helpers.Input @ line 16, column 9. new helpers.Input(serviceConfig: "camundaService", ^ 1 error
```

It is listed in the Deployment:

[image: deployment listing]

Do I miss something or is this not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a post in the Camunda forum, that helped me to solve this:

https://forum.camunda.org/t/groovy-files-cant-invoke-methods-in-other-groovy-files-which-are-part-of-same-deployment/7750/5

Here is the solution (that is not really satisfying - as it needs a lot of boilerplate code):

```
static def getScript(fileName, execution) {
    def processDefinitionId = execution.getProcessDefinitionId()
    def deploymentId = execution.getProcessEngineServices().getRepositoryService().getProcessDefinition(processDefinitionId).getDeploymentId()
    def resource = execution.getProcessEngineServices().getRepositoryService().getResourceAsStream(deploymentId, fileName)

    def scannerResource = new Scanner(resource, 'UTF-8')

    def resourceAsString = scannerResource.useDelimiter('\\Z').next()
    scannerResource.close()

    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
    return shell.parse(resourceAsString)
}

def helper = getScript("helpers/helper_classes.groovy", execution)
helper.myFunction("hello")
```